# jvm hangs when we use the while loop for executing a spy number and palindrome number program

Tags: java

i wrote a program to find if a number is spy number or not using while loop but when i execute it the jvm bar in the down right hand corner shows that the jvm is executing but the result is not executed so what should i do

i have tried to reset the jvm but it didnot work

```
class spy
{
    public static void main(int n)
    {
        int a=0;
        int b=0;
        int c= 01;
        int d=0;
        int num=n;
        while(n>0)
        {
            a=n%10;
            b=b+a;
            c=a*c;
            d=n/10;
        }
        if(b==c)
        {
            System.out.println(num+ "is a spy number");
        }
    }
}
```

i expect that jvm executes and the program prints whether the number is spy or not but the jvm is not executing and is showing that the work is in progress

Comment: `Java  !== JavaScript`

Comment: The main methods syntax is always `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: `n` does not change in your `while(n>0)` loop, so you will never exit.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a value for n > 0 your while loop is stuck in an infinite loop and never exits. The value of n never changes inside the loop, so it loops forever and never ends.